# How to get horse through gate in Sims 3?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have a rather big property, with an horse barn surrounded by a fence with a gate.

The gate is locked so that only my humans can open it and I can use one to bring the horse outside.

However, the whole property is surrounded by another fence, with a gate configured as the first one, but no Sim can take a horse after this gate!

They always show the tip about path blocked... is this some bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a glitch that many people experience. Try deleting the gate and replacing it or putting the gate in a different location.

Comment: I already removed and replaced the gate many times, I'll try to move it elsewhere... could it be related to the fact that the outer fence is exactly on the property's borders?